# form_for with association - how to provide parent id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, view, formbuilder

Assuming the `Post` - `Comment` model with the nested resources:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

How should the `app/views/comments/_form.html.haml` (erb will do as well) look like so that it also provides id of the post to attach the comment to?

Current only one way I know is to manually add hidden input with the post id. It looks dirty to me.

Is there any better way? I expected rails to understand the nested resource and automatically include the `post_id` as a hidden input.

```
= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|
  .field
    f.label :body
    f.text_field :body
    hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

EDIT: Using Mongoid, not ActiveRecord.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID of the post will actually be in the URL. If you type `rake routes` into your terminal/console, you will see that the pattern for your nested resource is defined as such:

```
POST    /posts/:post_id/comments    {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"}
```

Take a look at the HTML that is spit out by the `form_for` method, and look specifically at the  `action` url of the `<form>` tag. You should see something like `action="/posts/4/comments"`.

Assuming that you've defined `resources :comments` only **once** in your `routes.rb`, as a nested resource of `resources :posts`, then it is safe for you to modify the `CommentsController#create` action as such:

```
# retrieve the post for this comment
post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
comment.post = post
```

Or you can simply pass `params[:post_id]` to `comment` instance like so:

```
comment.post_id = params[:post_id]
```

I hope this helps.

For more information on nested forms/models, I recommend watching the following Railscasts:

- [Complex Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1)
- [Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Additionally, if you end up having to do this often, the inherited_resources gem automates a lot of the association management for you:

https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources